# Replace words in a string with data from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

using jquery I need to recognize sequences of characters in a string and replace them with different strings.

starting from this:

```
    var data = {
       name    : 'Brian',
       surname : 'Logan',
       city    : 'London'
    }

var msg = ' hello <name> <surname> from <city>! '
```

I need to process the string 'msg' to get this:

"Hello Brian Logan from London!"

I used a similar method when I worked in visual foxpro called 'textmerge', but I can not find a jquery function which does the same things.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: http://mustache.github.com/#demo

Comment: So you also want it to trim leading whitespace and capitalize the first character?

Comment: @Shmiddty no no I do not need that, @ Jay Blanchard I'm still trying to find a solution and I have not made ​​great progress .... I thought there was already a function in jquery that I did not know ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass a replacement function to `replace`:

```
String.prototype.format = function(mapping) {
    return this.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, function(match, name) {
        return mapping[name];
    });
};
```

You can call it like `msg.format(data)`.

Comment: Very clean solution, I like it.

Comment: I had some problems importing  the function in my project. worked for me writing it like this: `function textmerge (txt,data) {
        var oTxt = txt.replace(/<(.*?)>/g,function (match, prop) {
            return data[prop.toLowerCase()];
        });
        return oTxt;
    } `

Comment: @benVG: I was adding to the prototype of `String` so you could call it like `txt.format(data)`, but converting it to a function works as well.